# Forest plot using Metafor in R to remove overall estimate and wider scale

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

In creating a forest plot using `metafor` in R, I am having trouble making some aesthetics changes to the plot as I have limited knowledge of this package. Thanks!

1. I'd like to remove the overall estimate at the bottom of the plot, boxed in red. This is the code I'm using and res is a rma.uni object.

```
forest(res, at=c(-0.5, -1, 0, 0.5, 1), xlim=c(-16,6), atransf = mytransf,
       ilab=cbind(Z0, Z1, ZD0, ZD1), ilab.xpos=c(-9.5,-8,-6,-4.5), 
       cex=.75, 
       header="Subgroups", 
       mlab="", 
       xlab = 'ORR Relative Difference', 
       overall=FALSE, overall.hetstat = FALSE)
```

2. I would like to make the scale at the bottom wider and still spanning from -100 to 100. Right now it looks very narrow.
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to set the ylim manually and start by 0

   forest(res, at=c(-0.5, -1, 0, 0.5, 1), xlim=c(-16,6), atransf = mytransf,
   ilab=cbind(Z0, Z1, ZD0, ZD1), ilab.xpos=c(-9.5,-8,-6,-4.5),
   cex=.75, ylim=c(0,22),
   header="Subgroups",
   mlab="",
   xlab = 'ORR Relative Difference',
   overall=FALSE, overall.hetstat = FALSE)
2. to get a wider scale you have to experiment with the xlim

Comment: There are no `overall` or `overall.hetstat` argument for the `forest()` function in metafor (you are mixing together syntax for metafor and the meta packages). With `addfit=FALSE` one can remove the overall estimate (no need to change `ylim`). See: https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/forest.rma.html And yes, `xlim` needs to be adjusted to make more room for the points/CIs.